# Magento SSL: browsers alert to insecure content

Tags: magento, ssl, ssl-certificate

I install my ssl and work fine in my admin area (padlock green). But in my frontend, Chrome show an alert in padlock:

> The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has detected insecure content on the page

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

I open console and see the problems: images.

Magento set {{secure_base_url}}skin/, and my images are stored in skin/ folders. But in console, the images url is http://, not https://. How can I fix this?

**SOLVED**

Change images url on CSS. Simple.

Comment: See e.g. [Finding All Insecure Content on a Secure Page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4728507)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have hardcoded some images,css and Js with http:// that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to paste this in your index.php

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

or

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

got it [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19489/73429).

Sloved both `mixed content` and `http -> https` redirect issue.

Happy Coding.